# Option to add extra choices in django form

Tags: python, django, forms

I  am trying to create a model via a form that has multiple other models related to it. Say I have a model Publisher, then another model Article with a foreign key to Publisher. When creating a Publisher via a form, I want to create An article at the same time. I know how to do this via formsets. However, I don't know how to add a button that says add extra article at the same view, without having to be redirected to a new page and losing the old data since the form was not saved. What I want is when someone clicks add new article, for a new form for article to appear and for the user to add a new Article. Is this possible to be done in the same view in django, if so can someone give me and idea how to approach this?

I would show code or my attempts, but I am not sure how to even approach it.

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done using JavaScript. The hard part is to have the management form sync up with the number of rows.

But there's two alternatives:

1. Semi-javascript (Mezzanine's approach): Generate a ton of rows in the formset and only show one empty. Upon the click of the "add another row" button, unhide the next one. This makes it easier to handle the management form as the unfilled extra's don't need any work.
2. No fix needed: Add as many rows as is humanly sane. In general, people don't need 40 rows, they get bored with filling out the form or worry that all that work is lost when the browser crashes.

Hope this helps you along. Good luck!